# Is Tomcat 9 common classloader a URLClassLoader?

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

I have a custom library used by all of my applications that usually resides in the common library set of catalina.properties.  It assumes that the classloader is a URLClassLoader.

Under Java 8 even the basic AppClassLoader could be cast to URLClassLoader, and so could the classloader used by Tomcat 8 (which I suspect was a custom classloader made by the Tomcat designers).

So, under Java 9-11, in Tomcat 9... **can I expect the *common* classloader to be a URLClassLoader?**  If not, what is it?  And would there be a way for me to design a URLClassloader that could be plugged in to make *common* use it?

Thanks.

Comment: Tomcat is open-source, you can modify the code and make it do whatever you want (or rather, whatever you can figure out to code). --- As for whether the common loader is a URLClassLoader why don't you check it out for yourself? Cast it or use `instanceof`. Question down-voted because it "does not show any research effort" *(quoted tooltip of down-vote button)*.

Comment: *"days of coding"*? It would take you **minutes** only to create an empty webapp that simply tests whether the common classloader is a URLClassLoader. That is what is known as **research**, i.e. searching for *information*, in this case by **experimenting**. I would never suggest to migrate an entire web application before finding out that a crucial piece wouldn't function. That would be *ludicrous!*

Comment: *FYI:* If you had simply done your own research, you would already have a definitive answer to your question. It's now been more than 2.5 hours since you started writing the question, and you still don't have an answer. --- [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5221149)

Answer (score 2):

***TL;DR:** The common classloader of Tomcat 9 is a `URLClassLoader`*

To check which classloaders are used by a Tomcat application, create a small servlet to list the `ClassLoader` hierarchy.

```java
@WebServlet("/testcl")
public class ClassLoaderTest extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        for (ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(); cl != null; cl = cl.getParent()) {
            out.println(cl.getClass().getName());
            if (cl instanceof URLClassLoader)
                for (URL url : ((URLClassLoader) cl).getURLs())
                    out.println("    " + url);
        }
    }
}
```

Deploy to Tomcat and open the page of the servlet, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/test/testcl`

The shown page lists the classloaders and the URLs if the classloader is a `URLClassLoader`.

As can be seen in the output below, both the *webapp classloader* and the *common classloader* are URLClassLoader's:

- The 1st in the output is the Tomcat **WebApp** classloader, listing the `WEB-INF/classes` folder of the `test` webapp. It would also have listed any jar files in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder, if there had been any.
  It is a `URLClassLoader`.
- The 2nd in the output is the Tomcat **Common** classloader, listing the Tomcat `lib` folder and all the jar files found in that folder.
  It is a `URLClassLoader`.
- The 3rd in the output is the Java **App** classloader, representing the CLASSPATH of the Java application.
  In Java 8 and earlier, it is a `URLClassLoader`. In Java 9 and later, it is not a simple `URLClassLoader` any more, because of the Module system.
- The 4rd in the output is the Java **Extension/Platform** classloader.
  In Java 8 and earlier, it is a `URLClassLoader`. In Java 9 and later, it is not a simple `URLClassLoader` any more, because of the Module system.
- Not shown in output, because it is represented by the `null` value, is the Java **Bootstrap** classloader.

*Sample output with Java 8*

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/webapps/test/WEB-INF/classes/
java.net.URLClassLoader
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/annotations-api.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/catalina-ant.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/catalina-ha.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/catalina-storeconfig.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/catalina-tribes.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/catalina.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/ecj-4.13.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/el-api.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/jasper-el.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/jasper.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/jaspic-api.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/jsp-api.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/servlet-api.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-api.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-cs.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-de.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-es.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-ko.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-pt-BR.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-ru.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-zh-CN.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-jdbc.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-jni.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-util-scan.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-util.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-websocket.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/websocket-api.jar
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/bin/bootstrap.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader
    file:/C:/prog/Java64/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar
    file:/C:/prog/Java64/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar
    file:/C:/prog/Java64/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
    file:/C:/prog/Java64/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar
    file:/C:/prog/Java64/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
    file:/C:/prog/Java64/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
    file:/C:/prog/Java64/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar
    file:/C:/prog/Java64/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar
    file:/C:/prog/Java64/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
    file:/C:/prog/Java64/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar
    file:/C:/prog/Java64/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
    file:/C:/prog/Java64/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
```

*Sample output with Java 14*

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/webapps/test/WEB-INF/classes/
java.net.URLClassLoader
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/annotations-api.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/catalina-ant.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/catalina-ha.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/catalina-storeconfig.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/catalina-tribes.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/catalina.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/ecj-4.13.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/el-api.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/jasper-el.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/jasper.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/jaspic-api.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/jsp-api.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/servlet-api.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-api.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-cs.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-de.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-es.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-ko.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-pt-BR.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-ru.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-i18n-zh-CN.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-jdbc.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-jni.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-util-scan.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-util.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/tomcat-websocket.jar
    file:/C:/prog/tomcat-9.0.27/lib/websocket-api.jar
jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader
jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader
```

Comment: The question is NOT about the **webapp** classloader, it is about the **common** classloader.   They are NOT the same classloader.  I repeatedly said so in my earlier replies that I no longer see.  By focusing on the webapp classloader you are misleading and confusing anyone who is not an expert and reads this thread.  Common and webapp classloaders are two completely independent classloaders that even have a different relationship with their parent classloader.

Comment: @user321974 Please read what I write, I'm not just writing useless text. This answer fully covers the **common** classloader too. Classloaders are organized is a *hierarchy*, and for Tomcat there are 4 classloaders applicable to a webapp: 1) WebApp classloader (managed by Tomcat), 2) **Common classloader** (managed by Tomcat), 3) Bootstrap classloader, aka "App" (managed by JVM), 4) Ext/Platform classloader (managed by JVM). The ***common classloader*** is the second classloader listed in the output, with the Tomcat `lib` folder and all its jar files.

Comment: I see that now.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

ANSWER:
***Tomcat 9 still uses URLClassLoader*** for the **common** and later classloaders.

METHOD OF DETERMINATION:

1. The initial tests with a webapp had already confirmed that webapps used a URLClassLoader.  But since Tomcat launches webapps with their own ClassLoader, **that does not answer what happens... before Tomcat reaches the webapp initialization stage**.
2. So, to identify the classloader used by the ***common*** classloader before the webapp initialization stage  I had to use some weird tricks:

- Switched Tomcat logging to log4j
- Created a custom appender
- Placed the custom appender in the common library
- Configured log4j.xml to use the custom appender
- Added code to the appender to display the name and class of the classloader used by the appender.
- Since log4j logging gets activated by Tomcat before initializing any web applications, as demonstrated by the log4j entries... it answers the question.

I hope this answer is useful to those that stumble onto the same problem with Java 9 and later, and arrive to it when they google.